# Finite groups in group theory

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that finite group of even order comprises an element of order two?
I thought that if a group is finite it could have a finite set of elements with order two, couldn't it?

Comment: The statement doesn't exclude the possibility of a finite set of elements with order 2. It only says that there should be *at least one* element of order 2.

Comment: @Dreamer but how to find this element?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Define a relation $g \sim h$ if $g = h$ or $g = h^{-1}$. Show that this is an equivalence relation, and that an element is of order $1$ or $2$ iff it's alone in its equivalence class. Then count.

Comment: @T.Bongres don't understand how will it help

Comment: @Phill Every non-identity element that's not of order $2$ can be paired up with its inverse - so these classes all have size exactly $2$. Then there's another class with just the identity; put it together, and we're at least $1$ element short. This element has order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant to elaborate on T. Bongers' answer. Once you proved that the relation that he defined is an equivalence relation, you know that it covers the whole space. Then, for every element not of order $2$, the relation defines a class, namely that containing an element itself, and it's inverse (as defined by the relation). Therefore, these classes are all sets of size 2. However, one of these sets, the set containing $e$, has size $1$, since the inverse of $e$ is just $e$ itself. So, all these sets together contain an odd number of elements. The only way that $G$ can still have an even number of elements is therefore if it contains an element  order $2$. This is because for an element $a$ of order $2$ it holds that $a=a^{-1}$, which means that the equivalence relation will create a set with just $1$ element. Therefore, the total number of elements of $G$ is then again even.